# Tuleap: How to delete project

Tags: tuleap

I am a beginner with Tuleap. I created two projects and want to delete one of them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You must log in as an admin of your platform, go to the admin section, then projects, then select your project and set its status as deleted.

Comment: so it is not possible to  really delete but jsut mark as deleted?